# Expandable Listview group position text

Tags: android, expandablelistview

with

```
Log.e("GroupPosition", String.valueOf(groupPosition));
```

i can find the id of the Group

but how I can Access the text of the group id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh ;) found it myself

```
groupList.get(groupPosition)
```